# How can I create a registration form in Android using firebase

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I implement a registration functionality so that iam able to store extra user details for eg: gender, mobile number  age etc. Instead of just storing email and password which is by default provide by the firebase. Please help

Comment: in firebase authentication you can only store email and password if you enable email method. You can store mobile number if you enable phone method. But the others you can't you have to use firebase database for that

Comment: You can simply take input from user than save it to `firebase database`, while registering user. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical design pattern is to have a /users node in your Firebase that contains other user information. The child node stored in /users would have the uid as the key and then child nodes for the data you want to store.

It would look like this

```
rootRef
  users
    uid_0
      gender: "Male"
      mobile_number: "xxx-yyy-zzzz"
      age: "102"
    uid_1
      gender: "Female"
      mobile_number: "xxx-yyy-zzzz"
      age: "87"
```

Upon logging in, your app would know the uid of the user and can then read their data directly from the users node.